# Button on custom annotation

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have created a custom annotation with a button on the right side of it and a label on the left side.

It shows up good and the label text is changing perfectly, but for some reason when i click the button it doesn't react. I have connected an IBAction to it and it should work. But it just doesn't call my IBAction.

Does anyone have an idea why this button is ignoring my touch?

Thanks,

Comment: we can't guess without any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView 
                  viewForAnnotation:(id)ann 
         { 

         NSString *identifier = @”myPin”; 
         MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) 
         [aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier]; 
         if (pin == nil) { 
              pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:ann 
                                                           reuseIdentifier:identifier] 
                      autorelease]; 
         } else { 
              pin.annotation = ann; 
         } 


         //---display a disclosure button on the right--- 
         UIButton *myDetailButton = 
         [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; 
         myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23); 
         myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = 
         UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter; 
         myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = 
         UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter; 

         [myDetailButton addTarget:self 
                               action:@selector (checkButtonTapped:) 
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

         pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton; 
         pin.enabled = YES; 
         pin.animatesDrop=TRUE; 
         pin.canShowCallout=YES; 

         return pin; 
    } 



    -(void) checkButtonTapped:(id) sender
      { 

       //---know which button was clicked; 
       // useful for multiple pins on the map--- 
       // UIControl *btnClicked = sender; 
       UIAlertView *alert = 
       [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@”Your Current Location” 
                                       message :location 
                                      delegate:self 
                           cancelButtonTitle:@”OK” 
                           otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
       [alert show]; 
       [alert release]; 
       }
```

i use this code in my project and it work fine for me so you can try this.